# What is between my router and ISP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

When I am tracing a website, I get a result like this:

```
Tracing route to thepiratebay.org [104.31.10.186]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    17 ms     7 ms    18 ms  hitronhub.home [192.168.0.1]
  2    25 ms    29 ms    19 ms  INTEL_CE_LINUX [10.66.0.1]
  3    38 ms    39 ms    25 ms  rc1bb-tge0-9-0-12-1.vc.shawcable.net
  etc etc...
```

I know the first listing is my router and the third is my ISP's closest server. But the second is always the same IP and I want to know what it is...

Comment: It's your ISP, naturally. Your ISP's network terminates in your home.

Comment: Appretnly some newer "advanced modems" show up as that.

Comment: It's something Shaw modem do. Very stupid.

Answer (score 2):

INTEL_CE_LINUX is your router/modem.   The 192 address space is your internal LAN.  The 10 address space is the private IP of your modem and router.

Edit:  INTEL_CE_LINUX is a common firmware on newer routers.

Comment: I've seen more and more incidents lately of cable modems having their own internal NAT.  So if you have an internal router, you're essentially NATting twice.  This looks like one of those cases.

Comment: @CharlesBurge they have been doing that for at least a decade, if not longer.

Answer (score 1):

It could be one of a couple things.  As others have suggested, it could be your modem.  However, the increased latency makes me think that it is likely outside of your local network.  My guess would be that your ISP is using Carrier Grad NAT and that is the router handling NAT for your connection.